# How to know which part of my code takes more CPU

Tags: java, recursion, time, complexity-theory

I would like to know which lines of my code are using most of the time of execution. I am doing a planner algorithm, and to solve a specific problem I made, the computer needs 5 minutes to find the solution.

I am using a lot of recursion methods, I would like to know where is the most time wasted, so I can look into that lines and try to fix or refactor the code to see if it helps.

I know that there are Cyclomatic Complexity Methods. But I don't know how to use it on Eclipse. I am using Helios. Tried to install metrics2 and it just pops up errors on my Eclipse.

EDITED: SMALLER NEW QUESTION:

http://s7.postimg.org/frd8yjql5/diag.png
What does this means? Look at the Heap Size.. Always up and down.. does this affects CPU Speed? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a profiler, such as [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html)?

Comment: Look at `java profiling` first with the help of your preferred Internet search tool.

Comment: Profiling is what you want, if you download the netbeans IDE it comes with a basic cpu profiler, just click profile->attach profiler, and select the cpu profiler before clicking next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know which lines of my code are using most of the time of execution.

Run your code using a profiler.  Eclipse has profiling support, but I'd recommend using the profiler supplied as part of the JDK - VisualVM.

(I would not start by analysing the "big O" complexity.  Profile first, and that will tell you where to start looking.  Then you might want to formally or informally look at the algorithmic complexity of the hotspots.)

> I know that there are Cyclomatic Complexity Methods.

Cyclomatic complexity is not a predictor of performance.  It is (supposedly) a measure of code maintainability, not of computational complexity.  The same probably goes for the "metrics2" stuff, though I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, I will search VisualVM and try to install it :)

Comment: The `jvisualvm` has been bundled with the JDK since Java 6, update 7.

Comment: Yes while doing my search, I already found a tutorial how to run it :)
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

First start with an abstract analysis, only then go into detail and measure.

#### Abstract analysis

For the analysis, I would look at the complexity of your algorithm in the [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-notation). That is the abstract analysis of runtime (whereas metrics like Cyclomatic Complexity look at code quality).

For algorithm analysis, I find Cormen's book ["Introduction to algorithms"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) very good.

When you have an understanding of the complexity of your algorithm, you are able to check whether alternative algorithms would be better or where to do algorithmic improvements.

#### Measurement

Avoid [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization): Only when you are sure you have a good algorithm, you should go into detail and measure.

To check whether your theoretical analysis was correct and to look at the technical implementation (mainly to search for hotspots and optimize those), you can use [macro benchmarking tools](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and profilers like [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion, but actually I don't have much time to go into so deep analysis using expressions and maths, I am looking for something more pratical and to spot it right in time.
But again I say, thanks alot for your help, I will start with JVisualVM ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Hope you have enough time to look at my premature optimization link, because technical tuning usually makes the solution faster by a small factor only, whereas a better algorithm causes big (up to exponential) improvements. In short: There is nothing more practical than a good theory ;)

Comment: Yes its true, but the algorithm in my honest opinion is one of the best (GraphPlan), I might have done something wrong too.. Thats right.

Comment: Oh, it's not your own but a popular algorithm, IC. So are there other java implementations you could use to compare runtimes?

Comment: Yes there are, I could make a search.. I could compare, yes you are right.. Maybe the problem is the "problem" itself that is too hard :s

Comment: Hey Dave can you interpret the graphs showing the CPU Usage and Memory at JVisualVM ? Look at this diagnostic.. its running my program, trying to find the solution... look at the memory usage? Its always up and down (but it goes only till the middle of the maximium).. does this mean that It is constantly reaching the maximum of memory and then calls the garbage collector?
Does this has a bad impact of speed of execution?
Look at the diagnostic here: http://s7.postimg.org/frd8yjql5/diag.png
Thanks alot in advance!!

Comment: Hi DarkLink, yes, that's garbage collection. It looks like memory usage is not reaching the maximum and gc is not your runtime bottleneck (left graph). So I would only worry about gc if you had some (soft) real time constraints.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases profiler is the best, but sometimes it's better to use a simple stopwatch: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html

```
Basic usage:

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch().start();
doSomething();
stopwatch.stop(); // optional

long millis = stopwatch.elapsed(MILLISECONDS);

log.info("that took: " + stopwatch); // formatted string like "12.3 ms"
```

Comment: If you choose to benchmark in this fashion http://code.google.com/p/caliper/ is worth a look

Comment: Look henry what I would really like was to see the lines of codes being executed like in debug mode of eclipse.. So I could analyse which lines are most of times executed.. do you see? In debug mode I need to click to advance each step..